# Как заставить работать AlarmManager или TiME_TICK

Tags: java, android, service, broadcast-receiver, android-alarm-manager

Мое приложение - это чат, и я должен улавливать сообщения даже когда приложение закрыто(как вк или телеграмм), в голову пришла мысль что бы через определенное время запускался Broadcast, который бы проверял наличие новых сообщений и в случаи, если они есть запускал сервер который в свою очередь запускал бы уведомления, но при закрытии приложение AlarmManager перестает работать, как заставить ее работать в независимости от того запущено ли приложение или нет

манифест

```
 <receiver
            android:name=".broadcast.NotificationListener"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_TICK" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service
            android:name=".service.MessageService"
            android:exported="false" />
```

запуск AlarmManager

```
   val am = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,Intent(this,NotificationListener::class.java),0)
        am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 30000, pendingIntent)
```

Comment: AlarmManager работает независимо от того открыто приложение или нет.

Comment: Ну почему тогда я не получаю уведомление, в чем могут быть причины